# Program for printing all permutations of characters and printing the meaningful words

Tags: tcl, permutation

I need to write a program for making all the permutations of given characters and then only printing the meaningful words (according to dictionary)

Operating System: Linux (Centos5)

Comment: You should post your attempt...

Comment: Thanks @Jerry for pushing me.. I am posting my attempt as an answer.. hope looking for better solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel: there are permutations methods in the [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) package [struct::list](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html#25).

Also, optimize for performance by sending all the words in a single `exec` call to aspell.

```
package require struct::list

proc valid_words {words} {
    set aspell_results [lrange [split [exec aspell -a << $words] \n] 1 end-1]
    set ok {}
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $words]} {incr i} {
        if {[lindex $aspell_results $i] eq "*"} {
            lappend ok [lindex $words $i]
        }
    }
    return $ok 
}

set chars {t i m e}
set words [struct::list mapfor perm [struct::list permutations $chars] {join $perm ""}]
set valid [valid_words $words]
puts $valid                         ;# emit item mite time
```

Comment: Perfect @glennjackman ! Works thousand time faster!!

Answer (score 3):

I am trying this by forming different permutations and if length reaches to the possible length.. then it checks for the word in the dictionary using command aspell in Linux

hope this is a solution

```
set chars $argv
set ::len [llength $chars]
proc permutations items {
    set l [llength $items]
    if {[llength $items] < 2} {
        return $items
    } else {
        for {set j 0} {$j < $l} {incr j} {
            foreach subcomb [permutations [lreplace $items $j $j]] {
                lappend res [concat [lindex $items $j] $subcomb]
            }
        }
        foreach fe $res {
            if {[llength $fe] == $::len} {
                set wo [join $fe ""]
                set m [exec echo $wo | aspell -a]
                set m [split $m "\n"]
                if {[lindex $m 1] eq "*"} {
                    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $wo"
                }
            }
        }
        return $res
    }
}

permutations $chars
```

Comment: i had managed return value from aspell command to fetch out the exact match.

Comment: I think that an optimal solution might be to generate a dict of words from the dictionary containing all the words with their letters sorted alphabetically as key and the word itself as value. For example, you will find key 'ilnux' for value 'linux' in this dict. Then, you make a `proc` sort the input chars from a to z and compare it with the keys. When there's a match return the value (which can also be a list; e.g. `aemt` for `mate`, `meat`, `meta`, `tame` and `team`). Not sure how to write it up though.

Comment: thanks.. that might speed up the process... But is there anything in tcl which can perform such task..? aspell is an extra overhead..

Comment: If you can dump all the words from aspell, this shouldn't be too hard ^^ The new dict will be saved in a file so that you don't have to regenerate it again of course.